# Chrome Extensions PHP not working

Tags: php, google-chrome

I would like to use PHP in Chrome extensions. I've tried to change background.html to background.php but that doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can't do this. PHP is a server-side language. This would require all your users to install a PHP interpreter, which is not feasible. Perhaps if you used [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/) you would be able to bundle PHP somehow, but that most likely wouldn't be worth it at all.

Comment: I have some php code to use OAuth 2.0, to get the access token to use Prediction API. So how can I get this access token with Chrome Extensions?

Comment: There is an OAuth library for Chrome extensions; [here's a tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html).